# Crontab shows Import Error when using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cron

When using the crontab on my Mac to schedule some tasks using Selenium I get an import error (Couldn´t import module Selenium..).

(If I execute the script on the terminal without cron it works just fine)

I think it has something to do with the file paths (Either to Selenium or Python), but I haven´t found any solution on Google that solved the problem for me.

This is the code I am using at the moment to execute the script.

- - - - - /Users/julian/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/julian/Desktop/Code/Scratch.py

Comment: What exactly are you typing when you run the script on the terminal?

Comment: are you sure you are using same python installation, try `pip freeze` to see if you have selenium installed when called through crontab

Comment: @MrAlexBailey Exactly the same statement without the crontab time indicators.

So basically "/Users/julian/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/julian/Desktop/Code/Scratch.py"

Comment: @kapilkumar As I am using the same path it should use the same one. (At least I think so) Where should use/write "pip freeze" exactly? (Crontab, Py Script, etc.)